# NSNumber is not a subtype of UInt8

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I am trying to do some fairly simple SKShapeNode math to set the position of a shape node.  It looks like this:

```
    for var i = 0; i < 6; i++ {
        var pip: Pip = pips[i]

        // set position
        let x: CGFloat = tray2.frame.size.width - (i + 1) * pip.frame.size.width - (i + 1) * 2
        let y: CGFloat = tray2.frame.size.height - pip.frame.size.height - 1
        pip.position = CGPointMake(x, y)

        tray2.addChild(pip)
    }
```

However, in the 'let x...' line, an error is produced: "NSNumber is not a subtype of UInt8".  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `for var i : CGFloat = 0`

Comment: You can't mix ints and floats. Breaking up the multiple calculations into well named intermediates helps find errors. As a side effect there is better understanding of what is being done when someone else reads the code (or even you next month).

Comment: @BryanChen Thanks for the idea, but I cannot make i a float since I use it to pick items out of an array.

Comment: @Zaph This turned out to be the solution. I basically broke all of those formulas down into multiple tiny statements and the error vanished. Post this as the answer and I will select it.

Comment: @user1639164 Posted as an answer.

Comment: @BryanChen Iterating over a floating point variable is not a good idea. You can't ever be sure if the last `i` is `5.9` or `6.1`.

Comment: @Zaph I only see two answers, neither posted by you... Thanks tho!

Comment: I posted an answer and it was down voted, Since I could not duplicate your environment I could not test that my proposed implementation was correct and addressed the issue. So I deleted it. Your accepted choice is a good one. Consider adding your solution to your question or as an answer.

Comment: @Sulthan you are right. but in this case, IEEE754 guarantees the result to be exact number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot implicitly convert integers to floats. For example:

```
(i + 1) * pip.frame.size.width
```

this is invalid because `i` is an `Int`, `i + 1` is an `Int` but `pip.frame.size.width` is a `CGFloat`. This would work in languages like Obj-C where `i` would be implicitly cast to `CGFloat` but Swift has no implicit casts, so we have to cast explicitly.

The simplest fix is to convert `i` into a `CGFloat` first:

```
let floatI = CGFloat(i)
```

and then

```
let x = tray2.frame.size.width - (floatI + 1) * pip.frame.size.width - (floatI + 1) * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the expression in a CGFloat initializer to address the compiler error

```
for var i = 0; i < 6; i++ {
    var pip: Pip = pips[i]

    // set position
    let x: CGFloat = CGFloat(tray2.frame.size.width - (i + 1) * pip.frame.size.width - (i + 1) * 2)
    let y: CGFloat = CGFloat(tray2.frame.size.height - pip.frame.size.height - 1)
    pip.position = CGPointMake(x, y)

    tray2.addChild(pip)
}
```

Comment: Hm.  This did not work. I copied in your code snippet and got the very same error. Thanks though, I really appreciate your idea.  I'll play around with variations on it.